# Multiline input with variable number of string and integer tokens in C

Tags: c, input

My input file looks like this-

```
# 4
INS 0 3
DEC 0 0
DEL
INS 1 2
DEC 1 0
DEL
INS 2 1
DEC 2 0
INS 3 3
```

With this whole module having multiple occurences in the input. I want to read the input on a line-by-line basis and then based on first word(delimited by a space), perform a necessary function with the additional values (if present, as in the case of `#`, `INS` and `DEC`
operations).

How do I allow for reading of the possible extra values for the same?

So far, I used `fread` to read it line by line and then split it, but IMO that's too much work. I tried using `scanf("%[^\n]\n", variable)` but then  again I need to tokenise it.

Also, when trying to use `scanf("%[^\n] %[0-9] %[0-9]\n", var1, var2, var3)` specifies the need to use var2 and var3 as character arrays. That reduces the need to tokenise but gives garbage input.

Is there an easier way to do the same?

Ps- I'm using C on Ubuntu 17.10 for the same.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use `scanf`, use `fgets`, check whether the first char is `'#'`, if so, discard the line and get the next. You then use `sscanf` to parse the buffer for subsequent lines. If a parse of `if (sscanf (buf, "%3s %d %d", str, &n1, &n2) != 3)`, then `if (strncmp ("DEL", buf, 3) == 0)`, you know you have a `"DEL"` line. Your process is made easy by the fixed max length you expect.

Comment: Great minds think alike `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin tis yours today, I'll delete my redundant comments.  Welcome to the [MAS](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mutual_admiration_society)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continuing from the comments, using `scanf` for input for new (and not so new) C programmers is a minefield. `scanf` does not read and include the trailing `'\n'` unless you explicitly account for it in your *format string*. The *conversion specifiers* handle leading whitespace differently depending on whether you are reading number, character, or string values.

That is one of the primary reasons *line oriented* input functions such as `fgets` (or POSIX `getline`) are recommended when taking user input -- they provide a simple way to validate whether a complete line was read (e.g. get the length and check that the last char is `'\n'`) and consistently handle characters waiting in the input buffer.

Further, using `fgets` and then parsing the buffer allow separate validation of (1) the read, and (2) the parse of information. You can parse the input with whatever function from `string.h` fits the bill, with `sscanf` or simply by walking a pointer (or pair of pointers) down the buffer checking each character and taking whatever action is needed to make use of each part of the line.

A simple example making use of `sscanf` to parse could be similar to the following. The code expects the filename to read as the first argument, if no argument is given, it will read from `stdin` by default:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DEL "DEL"                   /* if you need constants, define them */
enum { MAXARG = 3, MAXC = 512 };

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int n1, n2;                 /* integer values from line */
    size_t ndx = 0;             /* line index */
    char buf[MAXC] = "",        /* buffer for line */
        cmd[MAXARG+1] = "";     /* buffer for 3-char command */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) { /* read each line in file */
        size_t len = 0;             /* buf length */

        if (*buf == '#') {  /* check if first char in line is '#', discard */
            fprintf (stderr, "line[%2zu] - discarding comment line.\n", ndx);
            ndx++;
            continue;
        }

        len = strlen (buf);                 /* get length */
        if (len && buf[len - 1] != '\n') {  /* validate last char '\n' */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: line too long, chars remain unread.\n");
            break;
        }

        /* check for 3 values, then 1 value == "DEL", otherwise throw error */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%3s %d %d", cmd, &n1, &n2) == MAXARG)
            printf ("line[%2zu] (3 vals) : %s %d %d\n", ndx, cmd, n1, n2);
        else if (strncmp (DEL, buf, MAXARG) == 0)
            printf ("line[%2zu] (1 val)  : %s\n", ndx, cmd);
        else
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid line: %zu\n", ndx);

        ndx++;
    }

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Using your data file, the data would be read and parsed as follows. Note the initial label tells whether there was 1 value or 3 values parsed from the line (zero indexed):

```
$ ./bin/misclines <dat/misclines.txt
line[ 0] - discarding comment line.
line[ 1] (3 vals) : INS 0 3
line[ 2] (3 vals) : DEC 0 0
line[ 3] (1 val)  : DEL
line[ 4] (3 vals) : INS 1 2
line[ 5] (3 vals) : DEC 1 0
line[ 6] (1 val)  : DEL
line[ 7] (3 vals) : INS 2 1
line[ 8] (3 vals) : DEC 2 0
line[ 9] (3 vals) : INS 3 3
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: This was very helpful but I was able to implement this from the comments itself. Thanks a lot for this.

Comment: In the flow, the sscanf scans the values anyhow wheteher or not all 3 paramaters were met, right? I had a doubt about this and was trying to use it again for repeated input.

Comment: Sure, glad to help. I went back and implemented the end of `buf` check for `'\n'` to validate a complete read. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: @Akshayanti, partially. When `sscanf` encounters a *matching failure* (the input doesn't match the specifier) or an *input failure* (there is not enough input for each *format specifier*) it stops reading at that point and nothing else is read. In the case of `sscanf` above, it will read `DEL` into `cmd` before any failure occurs. The `strncmp` check just validates it was `"DEL"` that was read.

Comment: ah okay, that clarifies things. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Additional question, sorry about that.

If the input is not of form %3s, does it raise an exception or only a max of 3 characters are read from the string?

Comment: You can do it several ways. You could just check the return values `int rtn = sscanf (buf, "%3s %d %d", cmd, &n1, &n2); if (rtn == MAXARGS) { /* all values read */ } else if (rtn == 1) {if (strcmp (DEL, cmd) == 0) {/* all good */} } else { /* handle error */}`

Comment: @Akshayanti - yes `%3s` uses `3` as the *field width* modifier that limits the read to `3` characters into `cmd` (insuring room for the *nul-terminating* character at the end).

Comment: Cool! I was wondering if I really need to use strncmp as compared to strcmp while checking for DEL condition. That solves it, thanks!

Comment: You do if you are checking with `buf` because remember, we haven't trimmed the `'\n'` from the end yet (it's simple to do), but the `sscanf` into `cmd` does that for us. So if you compare `cmd`, you don't need `strncmp`, but if you compare `buf` you do `:)`